# How do I do a pristine checkout with mercurial?

Tags: git, mercurial

How do I get the working directory state back to what it would have been from a new clone of the repository (Obviously I could clone my repository, but that seems a bit savage.)

With git I'd do:

```
git clean -xdn (dry-run, to see what I'm about to destroy)

git clean -xdf (force, to actually do it)
```

And I'm assuming that there's probably a subtly different mercurial equivalent, but I can't find it.

Comment: Do you intend to remove all files that aren't tracked in the repo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `git clean` command remove untracked files from the working tree, including ignored files. The equivalent Mercurial command is provided by the standard [purge extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PurgeExtension):

```
hg clean --all --print
```

Remove the `--print` to actually delete the files, remove `--all` to only delete untracked files and leave ignored files behind.

If you also want to discard local changesets that haven't been pushed, i.e., the equivalent of

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

then you need to enable the [mq extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) and run

```
hg strip "outgoing()"
```

Your local clone will now look just like when you first cloned it.

(Yes, we also have sharp tools in our toolbox, but they're hidden away until you decide to use them.)

Comment: mq extension link broken

Answer (score 2):

Use `update` with `-C` or `--clean` to update to a revision and discard any local uncommitted changes.

```
hg status   (to see what you're about to destroy)
hg update <revision> -C
```

If you don't want to modify the parent revision, you can also use `revert`:

```
hg revert -anC  (dry run)
hg revert -aC  (all files, no backups)
```

Use `hg help update` or `hg help revert` for documentation on options.