# Mercurial: "undoing" two or more commits

Tags: mercurial, rollback

In [How do I do a pristine checkout with mercurial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104676/how-do-i-do-a-pristine-checkout-with-mercurial/10144166) Martin Geisler discuss how to remove already Mercurial commit'ed files using:

```
hg strip "outgoing()"
```

But what if I I want to keep my added files which went into "`outgoing()`" - example:

Two users a and b — starting on the same changeset

User a:

```
echo "A" > A.txt; hg ci -M -m ""; hg push
```

User b (forgets to run `hg pull -u`):

```
echo "B" > B.txt; hg ci -M -m "" B.txt;
echo "C" > C.txt; hg ci -M -m "" C.txt;
```

If user b run `hg strip "outgoing()"` then B.txt and C.txt are lost. `hg rollback` is not an option since there are two commits.

Can user b revert his files as "locally added - nontracked", then do `hg pull -u`, which gets A.txt, then handle the add/commit/push for B.txt and C.txt later?

Martin Geisler answered this earlier in the mentioned thread (a comment which I deleted and moved here:

```
hg update "p1(min(outgoing()))"
hg revert --all --rev tip 
hg strip "outgoing()"
hg pull -u
```

Now user c can finalize his work in the new files B.txt and C.txt and commit+push those.

Other ways to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason user b can't just pull and merge?

Comment: @MartinGeisler - can the commit messages of the outgoing files be saved before they are stripped?

Comment: Never mind Martin, hg outgoing --stat
gives a good overview of what was removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is the `rebase` extension.  With your scenario:

1. A and B start with the same history.
2. A commits and pushs a change.
3. B commits two changes, but can't push because of A's commit.
4. B pulls A's change.
5. B runs `hg rebase` and pushes.

Before rebase:

```
Common ---------------------------- A (tip)
     \
      B1 - B2 (working parent)
```

After:

```
Common - A - B1 - B2 (tip, working parent)
```

Comment: Thats a very good alternative, at least if you want to keep the B1 and B2 as commits

Comment: Note that "hg rebase" requires all locally changed files needs to be send in via "hg commit".

Answer (score 2):

You could but, by doing so, you are working against one of the biggest features of a DVCS like mercurial, that is, to easily and reliably handle the merging of multiple lines of development  as in your case.  If user b's goal is to have a line of development with all three changes applied, then the standard way to do that in `hg` would be to just go ahead and do an `hg pull -u` which will create a new head containing the change(s) from user a (and any other changes pushed to repo used for pulling) and then use `hg merge` to merge the two heads, the head containing user b's two change sets and the other containing user a's change set (as pulled).  In a simple case like this one with no overlapping changes, hg should do all the right things by default.

```
$ hg pull -u
[...]
added 1 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files (+1 heads)
not updating: crosses branches (merge branches or update --check to force update)
$ hg merge
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
(branch merge, don't forget to commit)
$ hg ci -m "merge"
```

If there were conflicts between the two heads (i.e. both users committed changes to the same files), there might need to be conflict resolution editing as part of the merge; hg will tell you if that is the case.

Comment: Also a good comment. The only problem I have seen with this one is the the merge graph gets to look very ugly if the problem is that B made his commits a loooong time ago (but forgot to push). For that "hg rebase" is a good alternative

Comment: In real-world large projects, trying to optimize the repo graph is not a realistic goal.  If you do want to keep track of branch history, use Mercurial's named branch feature.  Unlike some other DVCS's (like `git`), each `hg` commit belongs to one and only one named branch and that branch is recorded with each commit.